# How to get custom Proxy fields to appear in developer tools

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a proxy that has a few debug fields which are stored internally. I am exposing them by specific field names, e.g. something like this in my handler:

```
    get(target, property, receiver) {
        if (property == "__debug1") return debug1
        ...
```

But when I look at (inspect) the object in Chrome developer tools, these pseudo-properties do not appear, even though if I do something like `obj.__debug1` it returns the pseudo-property.

I tried implementing all the other handler functions that seem related to enumerations: `ownKeys`, `getOwnPropertyDescriptor` and `has`, and these work if I call the corresponding functions directly.  But they never get called when I am inspecting the object (even doing something like putting it in the console using console.log, which allows me to directly inspect the value).

How do I get my pseudo-properties to show up for inspection during debugging?

Comment: Where exactly are you "storing" them? In a closure scope? Then inspect the scope of your handler functions. If you are storing them on the `target` of your proxy object, they should be directly visible in the inspection of the proxy. But no, logging a proxy does never cause its properties to be evaluated, your traps won't fire until explicitly access the properties.

Comment: Please post your whole code.

Comment: @Bergi I'm storing them as a closure in the function which constructs the Proxy

Comment: What is your proxy's target?

Comment: @Bergi A plain object.  Anyway, since it seems maybe it's not possible to do this, as a workaround I created a function that recurses into the object and created a regular mirror copy including the hidden fields.

Comment: Yeah, that should work. Alternatively, you can always inspect the trap closures. Depending on your use case, you should maybe even store them on the target object itself, that would be the easiest way to access them.